# Vertical space in command links in TaskDialog since v1.1

Tags: c#, .net, taskdialog

I have noticed a large, vertical space in my task dialog (the space between the command links' titles and instruction texts) which looks really bad. It started to appear right after I upgraded WindowsAPICodePack to version 1.1.

Here's the code:

```
TaskDialog td = new TaskDialog();
var b1 = new TaskDialogCommandLink("b1", "foo", "bar");
var b2 = new TaskDialogCommandLink("b2", "one", "two");
td.Controls.Add(b1);
td.Controls.Add(b2);
td.Caption = "Caption";
td.InstructionText = "InstructionText";
td.Text = "Text";
td.Show();
```

Here's the result:

[image: Ugly task dialog with vertical space in command links]

Before, "bar" would appear right below "foo", but now it looks as if there's an empty line between the two. Is this a problem on my end (and would anyone know what it might be) or are you guys also experiencing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've gotten the same bug in the 1.1 release.  It seems to be due to the `TaskDialogCommandLink` class's `toString` method `string.Format` with `Environment.NewLine`, which doesn't map cleanly when passed to the TaskDialog itself.

```
public override string ToString()
{
  return string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0}{1}{2}",
    Text ?? string.Empty,
    (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(instruction)) ?
        Environment.NewLine : string.Empty,
    instruction ?? string.Empty);
}
```

I use an implementation subclass anyway to make the arguments easier, and over-rode the method to pass a string containing a simple '\n', although I don't need to internationalize my application and so can do things a little more simply.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    string str;

    bool noLabel = string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Text);
    bool noInstruction = string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Instruction);

    if (noLabel & noInstruction)
    {
        str = string.Empty;
    }
    else if (!noLabel & noInstruction)
    {
        str = this.Text;
    }
    else if (noLabel & !noInstruction)
    {
        str = base.Instruction;
    }
    else
    {
        str = this.Text + "\n" + this.Instruction;
    }
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I noticed the same spacing issues with the API Code Pack v1.1 on Windows 8. [DougM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2383794/dougm) is correct, his `ToString()` override will solve the problem.

Here is an updated version, simply drop this class into your project and instead of using `TaskDialogCommandLink`, use `TaskDialogCommandLinkEx` instead.

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs;

internal class TaskDialogCommandLinkEx : TaskDialogCommandLink
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        string str;

        var noLabel = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Text);
        var noInstruction = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Instruction);

        if (noLabel & noInstruction)
        {
            str = string.Empty;
        }
        else if (!noLabel & noInstruction)
        {
            str = Text;
        }
        else if (noLabel & !noInstruction)
        {
            str = Instruction;
        }
        else
        {
            str = Text + "\n" + Instruction;
        }
        return str;
    }
}
```